# How to fill gap between 2 polygons using jts functions?

Tags: jts-topology-suite

I have 2 polygons that are supposed to be exactly adjacent to each other but sometimes they form a gap/overlap in between. For e.g. in the below image there is a small gap on one side and a small overlap on the other side. How to make them completely adjacent to each other using JTS functions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that know if JTS supports filling the gaps directly. OpenJUMP that is a Java GIS program based on JTS has a special tool for that task. The tool is included in the OpenJUMP Plus version and it can be found from Plugins - Topology - Coverage cleaner.

[image]

The source code is within the topology extension code https://github.com/openjump-gis/topology-extension/blob/main/src/main/java/fr/michaelm/jump/plugin/topology/TopologyExtension.java. This may be the exact place https://github.com/openjump-gis/topology-extension/blob/a365a36c3db43200a0c6b8e34a50255e0df33c7d/src/main/java/com/vividsolutions/jcs/plugin/clean/CoverageCleanerPlugIn.java.

I believe that the coverage cleaner plugin is written when JTS did not have necessary classes. The situation may be different now and for example this might be able to snap the almost adjacent polygons together.
https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/noding/snapround/SnapRoundingNoder.html